# couldn't get a property value from an object in angular and firebase2

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

**Why I can't get different property values from an object?**
I am actually following a material where a variable clients is initialized in the constructor as shown below.

```
@Injectable()
export class ClientService {

  clients: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
  client: FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;

  constructor(
    public af: AngularFireDatabase
  ) { 
    this.clients = this.af.list('/clients') as FirebaseListObservable<Client[]>;
  }

  getClients(){
    return this.clients;
  }
}
```

The getClients() method is used in the ngOnInit() method of ClientComponent.

```
export class ClientsComponent implements OnInit {

  clients: Client[];

  constructor(
    public clientService: ClientService
  ) { }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.clientService.getClients().subscribe(clients => {
      this.clients = clients;
      console.log(this.clients);
    })
  }

}
```

Now, I tried to show clients detail by looping through the loop.

[image]
I can see the object in the console log, but the data is not shown in front end.
[image]

Comment: Hint: get db data in `getClients` instead of having that in constructor. But that's not your problem at this time. But take a look at how your data is built. You have nested objects in your array :)

Comment: Thanks, your comment helped. The culprit was nested objects which was set in firebase db.